# Cryptarithmetic puzzle generic solution in Python 3

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, recursive-backtracking, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I am stuck with this problem statement, My code does work but I used `itertools.permutations` and that makes it very slow. Moreover, I don't know how to make it generic for all or any input. I  think I have to use backtracking but I am not use how to use it here.

Any valuable suggestion or advice or code is welcome. And yes this is an assignment and I am not asking for whole code. Thanks!

Here is problem statement:

> Substitute different digits (0, 1, 2, .., 9) for different letters below, so that the corresponding addition is correct, and the resulting value of M O N E Y is as large as possible. What is the value?
>
> SHOW + ME + THE = MONEY

There are 3 solutions satisfy the equation: 10376, 10267, 10265. Therefore, the correct one is (the largest) 10376. If there are multiple mappings evaluating to the same maximum value, output all of them.

The assignment:

> Write a program in Python, which can always find the correct solution for this kind of problem.

```
import time
import itertools


def timeit(fn):
    def wrapper():
        start = time.clock()
        ret = fn()
        elapsed = time.clock() - start
        print("%s took %2.fs" % (fn.__name__, elapsed))
        return ret
    return wrapper


@timeit
def solve1():
    for s in range(1, 10):
        for e in range(0, 10):
            for n in range(0, 10):
                for d in range(0, 10):
                    for m in range(1, 10):
                        for o in range(0, 10):
                            for r in range(0, 10):
                                for y in range(0, 10):
                                    if distinct(s, e, n, d, m, o, r, y):
                                        send = 1000 * s + 100 * e + 10 * n + d
                                        more = 1000 * m + 100 * o + 10 * r + e
                                        money = 10000 * m + 1000 * o + 100 * n + 10 * e + y
                                        if send + more == money:
                                            return send, more, money


def distinct(*args):
    return len(set(args)) == len(args)


@timeit
def solve2():
    #letters = input("Enter your string: ")
    #letters1 = list(letters)
    letters = ('s', 'h', 'o', 'w', 'm', 'e', 't')
    digits = range(10)
    for perm in itertools.permutations(digits, len(letters)):
        sol = dict(zip(letters, perm))
        if sol['s'] == 0 or sol['m'] == 0:
            continue
        send = 1000 * sol['s'] + 100 * sol['e'] + 10 * sol['n'] + sol['d']
        more = 1000 * sol['m'] + 100 * sol['o'] + 10 * sol['r'] + sol['e']
        money = 10000 * sol['m'] + 1000 * sol['o'] + 100 * sol['n'] + 10 * sol['e'] + sol['y']
        if send + more == money:
            return send, more, money


print(solve1())
print(solve2())
```

Comment: do you just expect additions as input or also subtractions or even more complex equations?

Comment: Oh and another question: the solutions you posted are the mappings for MONEY, right? So 10376 means M=1, O=0, ... what about the mapping of the other letters?

Comment: SO is not about solving your homework and/or puzzles.

Comment: @caenyon, yes only addition, yes it is mapping for money and you are right...M=1,O=0 and so on.

Comment: @zaph, sorry didn't get that!

Comment: i think you should post a part of your code so that we can take that as a starting point

Comment: @caenyon, sure i posted my code

Comment: ok, am I right that it's allowed to substitute two different letters with the same number? so for example S=9 and E=9?

Comment: @caenyon, unique letter has unique number. same letter has same number.

Comment: The question has "SHOW + ME + THE = MONEY" but the code has "send + more == money".

Comment: @zaph, yes question has "SHOW + ME + THE = MONEY" but to try i used "send + more == money" but it is not working as expected. I am not sure how to work for any input solution. I don't know how to make a generic solution for any input in this code?

Comment: Your title says 'generic solution' but your body implies 'Print them all, but the correct one is the largest' (in this example, the most efficient way is to iterate over candidate permutations of  ('M','O','N','E','Y') in decreasing order from 9..0 or 9..1)). The most generic solution will simply find all solutions; what you do with them beyond that (sorting, ranking) is postprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your `solve2` method as a starting point and implemented a simple parser for equations `'word [+ word]*n = word'`. The function `get_value` computes the resulting integer value after substituting all letters in word with their associated numbers. The rest is just going through the permutations like you did and comparing the sum of left words with the right word.

Here's the code:

```
import itertools


def get_value(word, substitution):
    s = 0
    factor = 1
    for letter in reversed(word):
        s += factor * substitution[letter]
        factor *= 10
    return s


def solve2(equation):
    # split equation in left and right
    left, right = equation.lower().replace(' ', '').split('=')
    # split words in left part
    left = left.split('+')
    # create list of used letters
    letters = set(right)
    for word in left:
        for letter in word:
            letters.add(letter)
    letters = list(letters)

    digits = range(10)
    for perm in itertools.permutations(digits, len(letters)):
        sol = dict(zip(letters, perm))

        if sum(get_value(word, sol) for word in left) == get_value(right, sol):
            print(' + '.join(str(get_value(word, sol)) for word in left) + " = {} (mapping: {})".format(get_value(right, sol), sol))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solve2('SEND + MORE = MONEY')
```

If you're only interested in the maximum value for the right word, you can change the permutation that it starts with the highest number for the right word (e.g. 98765 for MONEY) and goes down one by one until it finds the first match.

**Backtracking**

OK, the idea here would be to build up the substitutions one by one and check if the equation can be fulfilled between each step.

```
For example:
1. set S = 9
2. check if equation can be fulfilled:
    2.1. if yes: set a value for the next letter and go to 2
    2.2. if no: select next value for S
```

in this case, checking whether the equation can be fulfilled is not so easy.

i'd try the following:

min: minimum value in range(10) that has not been used for a substitution so far

max: maximum value in range(10) that has not been used for a substitution so far

substitute every letter on the left side that has not been substituted so far with the min/max value and compare the sum with the number of the right side after substituting with the max/min value.

```
Example:
equation = 'SEND + MORE = MONEY'
1. substitute M = 2
2. check:
   max = 9, min = 0
   compare max on left side with min on right side: 9999 + 2999 = 20000
   compare min on left side with max on right side: 0000 + 2000 = 29999
   if max_left < min_right or min_left > max_right:
       the current chosen substitutions (M = 2 in this example) can not lead to a valid solution.
```

Do you get the idea?

Comment: Thank a lot, let me try according to your advise!

Comment: @cenyon, Thanks for your efforts. I have a question, here we both are using permutation so if there is a big input then it will be very slow. I think I should use backtracking to reduce time. But I don't know how to implement backtracking in cryptarithmetic, Can you please help or provide some advise? Thaks!

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, let me try this, I will avoid using brute-force approach! :)

Comment: can u share the code using backtracking?

Answer (score 1):

```
    def isCryptSolution(crypt, solution):
        newsol = list(zip(*reversed(solution)))
        newstring1 = ''
        total = 0
        for word in range(len(crypt)-1):
            subtotal, sol_total = 0, 0
            newstring = ''
            for char in crypt[word]:
                idx = newsol[0].index(char)
                newstring = newstring + newsol[1][idx]
                subtotal = int(newstring)
                # if newstring[0] == '0':
                #     return False
            total = total + subtotal
        for char1 in crypt[-1]:
            nidx = newsol[0].index(char1)
            newstring1 = newstring1 + newsol[1][nidx]
            sol_total = int(newstring1)
        if total == sol_total and newstring[0] != '0':
            return True
        elif total == 0 and newstring[0] == '0' and len(newstring) == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

crypt = ["SEND", "MORE", "MONEY"]
solution = [['O', '0'],
            ['M', '1'],
            ['Y', '2'],
            ['E', '5'],
            ['N', '6'],
            ['D', '7'],
            ['R', '8'],
            ['S', '9']]

isCryptSolution(crypt, solution)
```